# Ajax with jQuery and getting back from the detail to result page?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a result page loaded with jquery/ajax in a div, when i clicked the details of one of the results it load the details in the div. But now when you hit the back button it doesn't go to the previous results?? Or a simple go back with javascript:history(-1); doesn't work

How can i fix this??

Comment: You do realize that Ajax is really not loading the page.  As to "fix" this, you will need to preserve the previous value, and do ANOTHER ajax call to get that one back...

Comment: @mark, could you point me in the right direction. I have a simplified version of my problem here bldd.nl/stackoverflow/pagination/
regards

Comment: Some questions come to mind first, was the first result loaded with Ajax, or with the page originally?  And if original, can you identify and load that result via Ajax as well? If you have access to Google you can use "Ajax and back button" to find a lot of related results that might assist you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to actually modify the URL in some way for the browser to pick up the history. Typically, this is done by modifying the anchor text (that is, the stuff after the "#").

Just google for "anchor navigation" for plenty of samples of how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The AJAX request is not loading a page. The back button is getting the last page, and javascript:history(-1) is doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not problem because the user is not transfer to new page he still in same page but some data information is updated.